# How to make async wait for the next?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, async-await

I have an array with foods and every food has some measures. I have to insert them into two databases `foods` and `measures`, but I have to check if there is an existing measure in the `measures` database. It is asynchronous code, and I get multiple measures with the same `name`. How can I make it to wait before checking if the measure exist in the database?

```
        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
            var foods = [];

            async.each(result, function(obj, callback) {
                var entity = mapper.fromNutritionApiToDatabase(obj);
                var measures = mapper.mapMeasure(obj);
                async.each(measures, function(item, callback) {
                    //   console.log("Item : " + item.label);
                    var en = {
                        name: {
                            en: item.label,
                            bg: item.label
                        }
                    };

                    FoodMeasureRepository
                        .findOne({
                            "name.en": item.label
                        })
                        .then(function(result) {
                            // console.log("Result " + result);
                            if (result) {
                                entity.measures.push({
                                    measureId: result._id,
                                    value: parseInt(item.eqv)
                                });
                                callback();
                            } else {
                                FoodMeasureRepository
                                    .insertOne(en)
                                    .then(function(result) {

                                        entity.measures.push({
                                            measureId: result._id,
                                            value: parseInt(item.eqv)
                                        });

                                        callback();
                                    })
                            }
                        })
                        .catch(function(err) {
                            callback(err)
                        });
                }, function(err) {
                    if (err) {
                        callback(err);
                    } else {
                        foods.push(entity);
                        callback();
                    }
                });

            }, function(err) {
                if (err) {
                    console.log(err);
                } else {
                    resolve(foods)
                }
            });
        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK.

What is happening is that multiple measures are discovering that there is no measure in the database before the first of them adds it,  but as the others have also found that it isn't there they also all add it.  There are two ways to solve this:

- Make a copy of what you know about the database,  don't query the same thing twice
- Implement a function that does an insert if not there on the database side

The second one is nicer,  but often there are reasons you can't do it.

So here is an example of a local knowledge store.  In this both in progress Promises and results from the database are stored in the "DB_contents" map,  keyed by the item they are querying for.

Once the first query is made all subsequent queries will queue up.  When the first query completes it will propagate its result to any waiting queries and store it for future reference.

```
var DB_contents = {}; // our knowledge and queue store
function ensure_DB_has_measure(label) {
  return new Promise(function(_pass, _fail) {

    // A more generalised fail function for clarity
    function fail(err) {
      // Remove the queue so nothing else waits
      var original = DB_contents[label];
      delete DB_contents[label];

      // Inform everything in the queue of the failure
      if(original instaceof Array) {
        original.forEach(function(promise) {
          promise.fail(err);
        });
      }

      // Follow own failure method
      _fail.apply(_fail, arguments);
    }

    function pass(result) {
      // Replace the queue with the result so future calls don't query
      var original = DB_contents[label];
      DB_contents[label] = result;

      // Inform all waiting calls of the result
      if(original instanceof Array)
        original.forEach(function(promise) {
          promise.pass(result);
        });

      // Follow own completion path
      _pass.apply(_pass, arguments);
    }

    // Check to see if it needs to queue
    if(DB_contents[label] instanceof Array) {
      DB_contents[label].push({pass:pass, fail:_fail});

    // Or if the value is already here it can return
    } else if(DB_contents[label]) {
      _pass(DB_contents[label]);

    // Or it needs to be fetched
    } else {
      // Initialise the queue
      DB_contents[label] = [];

      // Check for pre-existence
      FoodMeasureRepository
      .findOne({"name.en":label})
      .then(function(result) {
        if(result) {
          pass(result);
        } else {
          FoodMeasureRepository
          .insertOne({name:{en:label, bg:label}})
          .then(pass)
          .catch(fail);
        }
      })
      .catch(fail)
    }
  });
}

// The above should go outside the async calls
// This can now replace the contents of your second async function body
ensure_DB_has_measure(item.label)
.then(function(result) {
  entity.measures.push({
    measureId: result._id,
    value: parseInt(item.eqv)
  });
  callback();
})
.catch(function(err) {
  callback(err);
})
```